# Handle an event with LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, javascript, .net-3.5

I have a LinkButton click event in asp.net 3.5 that I must assess whether a value exists and return a alert.
I have no idea how you can do. I think we need to Ajax
Can someone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple solution without getting too involved with a lot of AJAX.

If you have your link button in your page:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myButton" Text="Click me" OnClick="myButton_Click" runat="server" />
```

Add an event handler in your page's code behind:

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check some stuff on the server...

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "myJsMethod()", true);
}
```

This example will call a JavaScript function called **myJsMethod** on your page which you can then call any JS you like including your alert().

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the `OnClientClick` handler for the `LinkButton` assuming that the value you want to check is available client side:

```
OnClientClick="if $('#yourID').val() == 'something')
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to override this lock?');
    else return true;"
```

If it is not available client side then you would need to do an ajax call to check the value and replace the `if` check in the example above with it or have your server side code add an inline javascript alert.